# Is a operator Binary or Unary in Postfix

Tags: math, postfix-notation

I wrote a simple shunting yard algorithm to convert my mathematical expression to postfix notation and it  works great, but i wonder if there is a easy way to know wether or not a operator in postfix is binary or not. here is a example:

```
33+ //in this case the plus is binary because it adds the two threes
3+ //here it is unary

3333+++- //The minus is unary, the plus signs are all binary
```

The reason I want to know this is because I would like to take the result and convert it into a binary which contains binary and unary nodes. Btw I'm programming in java.

Comment: Your syntax is fundamentally ambiguous. `-(3-3)` and `3-(-3)` both become `33--`.

Comment: This problem cannot be solved with some clever code trick. You need to change your notation.

Comment: Yeah, you are right. Thanks for the answer. Which notation would be better than postfix?